# libgdx android doesn't show model (black screen)

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx

I'm new in LibGDX.
I've tried to apply some tutorial I've read online to load a model in libGDX.
The problem is that I have a black screen when the app is loaded on my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.3), no error according to LogCat.
The code is this:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(7f, 7f, 7f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("data/skeleton.g3db", Model.class);
    loading = true;



    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
}

private void doneLoading() {       
       Model I_model = assets.get("data/skeleton.g3db", Model.class);
       ModelInstance I_instance = new ModelInstance(I_model);
       I_instance.transform.setToTranslation(-5f, 0, -5f);
       instances.add(I_instance);
       loading = false;
    }

@Override
public void render() {
    if (loading && assets.update())
        doneLoading();
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    modelBatch.dispose();
    model.dispose();
    assets.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
```

}

The model "skeleton" is taken online as .fbx and converted in .g3db with fbx-conv.
Is a code or model error?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you're models out of the camera frustum? Maybe set the model instance's transform to identity to check if that's the issue. Also try setting the clear color to something other than black to see if you can see the silhouette of the object, in which case there is a lighting issue.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've added this line in render(): Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
and now I see everything blue instead of black!

Comment: Changing the model I'm now able to see its black "structure". Maybe light problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the direction of the light, because I think two points of lighting here telling that the model has textures appear.
[image]

is possible that the model is getting bad light, 
use;

PointLight set (float r, float g, float b, float x, float y, float z, float intensity)

```
float intensity = 1f;

environment.add(new PointLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.8f, intensity));
```

and tray change variable intesity in test for example 100;

Comment: Nothing changes with the following code: environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f)); environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f)); float intensity = 100f; environment.add(new PointLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, intensity)); (PointLight.set needs 7 parameters) Sorry but I'm not able to formatting code in comments –

Comment: @Matt I have no idea, but you have to change cre parameters: -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f by others, has the look of the light comes from an angle that will not illuminate all objects

Answer (score 0):

Hello and sorry for my English, I have not much experience with models, but when you assign

cam.position.set (7f, 7f, 7f);

cam.lookAt (0,0,0);

and then you say

I_instance.transform.setToTranslation (-5F, 0, -5F);

is not far outside the range of vision of the camera? it's just a question maybe this error out there

Edit;

I_instance.transform.setToTranslation(-5f, 0, -5f);

DirectionalLight().set(float r, float g, float b, float dirX, float dirY, float dirZ)

Dirz your not is beyond the scope of the model, -5F changes by aver 1f think if you see that the lighting is not arrived

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the model, using another found online and now I can see the model "structure" without the texture (I can see the black model on blue screen). I'm trying to figure out if it is a model or light error :)

Comment: I don't know why but if I try to load that model (ship.g3db) the app doesn't work: it says that can't load the model even if it correctly located in assets/data folder (the same folder I put the other model). Changing that model to the older one, it "works" (with the usual problem)

Comment: nothing happened! Loading the model of a desk i obtain this:
http://imageshack.com/a/img746/9977/VzpF7c.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my problem was that the model loaded really big, and the camera was in the model. So try either scaling your model down, or moving the camera back a lot.